# Did the speaker here have to be natural? or have to do unnatural things?

Tags: meaning

In Greenmantle, by John Buchan, an American government official was on a secret mission in Turkey, and his friend, who had been playing a part for the last month, was asking him whether his job is tiring. So he answered:-

> We’ve only got to be natural. We wear our natural clothes, and talk
> English, and sport a Teddy Roosevelt smile, and there isn’t any call
> for theatrical talent. Where I’ve found the job tight was when I had
> got to be natural, and my naturalness was **the same brand** as that
> of everybody round about, and all the time I had to do unnatural
> things. It isn’t easy to be going down town to business and taking
> cocktails with Mr Carl Rosenheim, and next hour being engaged trying
> to blow Mr Rosenheim’s friends sky-high.

I didn't understand this part; Did he have to be natural? or have to do unnatural things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buchan uses two slightly different nuances of 'natural': (1) the speaker has to 'be' (behave, act) in a 'natural' (relaxed, friendly, normal, unthreatening) way when meeting people socially, and (2) the speaker has, at the same time, to secretly 'do' (perform, carry out) actions as a secret agent, that are 'unnatural' (dangerous, threatening, ruthless), often involving the same people he has met socially.

Greenmantle was published in 1916, and you may find some old-fashioned usages in it, although these are not among them.